# Get a Specific WeekDay date after a date

Tags: laravel, octobercms, php-carbon

I am trying to implement a delivery process that occurs at specific days of week for each region. So, in a Region that delivers on Tuesdays and Thursdays I need to be able to get next eligible date based on the date the product will be available. So, if I will have it read on the 5th, O need to get the date for the next Tuesday or Thursday.

I started implementing it on Carbon, but I and creating a lot of loops through dates, testing dates and checking if its valid. something of getting product availability date and checking each day after it if its a monday Tuesday or Thursday ... etc ///I am sure, using Carbon, will have a better way to do it.

Any hint on how to do that ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Define a date:

`$date = Carbon::now();`

Now you have to get the day:

`$day = $date->dayOfWeekIso`

If `$date` is monday, then you will get a integer and that would be 1. That is because: 1 (monday), 2 (Tuesday), ..., 7 (sunday).

Now that you have this number you just need to apply some simple logic.

If the number you get is a 2 (Tuesday) then you will need to add two days to your `$date` in order to get the delivery date:

`$delivery_date = $date->addDays(2);`

If your day is equal 4 (Thursday), then you need to add 6 days to your `$date` so that would give you the next Tuesday:

`$delivery_date = $date->addDays(6);`

I think that's what you want! I hope it helps!